# Travelling through dubia to brisbane

Tags: visas

I am travelling through Dubia and staying there for two days before travelling onto Brisbane I have a British subject passport do I need a different visa from my husband who is a British citizen

Comment: Do you mean Dubai?

Comment: Are you asking about transiting in the UAE, or entering Australia? Or both? The format of this site works best to get you the answers you need if you make two separate posts, one for each.